# How to restore MaxDB instance when no backup medium is available?

Tags: database, disaster-recovery, maxdb

I have a question about moving MaxDB databse instance from a broken server, when the files of that server have been restored, to a newly installed server?

The question I asked is here: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3249060

Is it possible to restore database from another database server copying just config and data folder?

**This is the situation I have:**

1. There was a server (MaxDB version 7.5.00.31) that broke, all files restored - there was just one database, lets say mydb.
2. I installed another server version 7.5.00.34 and created new instance of mydb database.
3. As there was no backup madium for the db I copied config and data folders from the old server and tried to start the database. It failed creating Data-1-1.bad file saying -8888 error broken connection.

Is it possible at all to recreate database only from data volumes on a different server? Lets assume we can keep the directory structure.

I appreciate any help :)

Thanks,

Sylwester

**UPDATE:**
I will answer this question, as I managed to do that pretty much the way I described it in the question.
The data files must have been corrupted after recovery. Next recovery approach must have
overcome that issue.

So the steps were:

1. Install new MaxDB environment.
2. Create new instance of the database keeping the directory structure the same as before the crush.
   Don't know if the directory structure has to be maintained or not though.
3. Stop the database (it will be started after creation).
4. Swap the data and config files of the database.
5. Restart the database - should be ok provided that the data files are not corrupted.

I also updated the question here: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3249060

Thanks,

Sylwester